# How to convert a iterator (FormData) to an object

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6

Given a `form` element `new FormData(form)` returns us an iterator.

```
// [["key1", "val1"],["key2", "val2"]]
console.log([new FormData(form)...])
```

I would now like to convert this to an object of the form:

```
{ "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2" }
```

Using ES6/7 features (supported by babel).

**Any ideas if this is possible to do in a functional approach?**

Comment: _"One quick and dirty approach I found"_ Approach at post does not appear to return all properties, values of `FormData` object?

Comment: @guest271314 a u're right - removed it

Comment: You know, an `object literal` would be text in source code. You probably meant something like a plain object

Comment: Hm, `var o = {}; for (var [key, [o[key]] of formData.entries()); return o` should do.

Comment: Can it be that https://gist.github.com/lukehorvat/133e2293ba6ae96a35ba is as fancy as possible?

Comment: @Bergi `var o = {}; for (var [k, v, z = !(o[k] = v) || void 0] of formData); console.log(o, z)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `.reduce` the *Array* made by using the spread `...` operator

```
[...new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))].reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
    o[k] = v;
    return o;
}, {}); // Object {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
```

Comment: Is `FormData` object an iterable?

Comment: @guest271314 https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata `iterable<USVString, FormDataEntryValue>;`

Comment: @guest271314: You've used `for of` on a `FormData` instance in your own answer and are asking now whether it's iterable?

Comment: even more immutable and one line: `[...formData].reduce((o, [k, v]) => ({...o, [k]:v}), {});`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Object.fromEntries(iterable);`

[From documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

> **Parameters:**
>
> `iterable` - An iterable such as Array or Map or other objects
> implementing the iterable protocol.
>
> **Return value:**
>
> A new object whose properties are given by the entries of
> the iterable.
>
> **Description:**
>
> The `Object.fromEntries()` method takes a list of key-value
> pairs and returns a new object whose properties are given by those
> entries. The iterable argument is expected to be an object that
> implements an `@@iterator` method, that returns an iterator object, that
> produces a two element array-like object, whose first element is a
> value that will be used as a property key, and whose second element is
> the value to associate with that property key.

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("a", 111);
formData.append("b", 222);
formData.append("c", 333);

console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for..of` loop

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("a", 123);
formData.append("b", 456);
var obj = {};
for(let prop of formData) {obj[prop[0]] = prop[1]};
console.log(obj)
```

---

Alternatively, using `rest element`, `FormData()` which returns an `Iterator`, `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("a", 123)
formData.append("b", 456)
var res = (d, it = [...d], r = {}, t =!(it.forEach(([k, v]) => {r[k] = v}))) => r;
console.log(res(formData))
```

Comment: Using `… of formData.entries()` isn't wrong either. Being more explicit some would even argue it's better.

Comment: @Bergi Have been trying to do `var [...obj] = [...formData.entries()]; obj = obj.reduce(function(o, prop) { o[prop[1]] = prop[1] }, {})` though incorporating `.reduce()` part into first portion of of rest element; or assigning directly without using `.reduce()`

Comment: `[...obj]` makes no sense, it's equivalent to assigning to `obj` directly. Or just use `Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce(…)` in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define an object and loop through the iterator to get the values from it and assign it to the object you created.

```
var fd = new FormData(someForm);
po = {};
for (var key of fd){
  po[key] = fd[key];
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `fd.get(key)`. A `FormData` instance is more like a `Map` rather than an object.

Comment: I did test this in Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m (64-bit) before posting, I have never gotten `.get` to work, though I haven't tried it in a while.

Comment: Hm, the iterable interface appears to be quite new anyway. Not sure what Chrome implements.

Answer (score 0):

using fuctional way

```
function getFormObj(form) {

 return  [...new FormData(form)].reduce((prev, [key,val]) => {
    return Object.assign(prev, {[key] : val}) ; 
  }, {}) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but in recent times I think it can be solved using the following  (just in case someone finds it useful):

```
let fd = new FormData(form)...
console.log(Array.from(fd.entries()))
```